# Refresh table after seconds

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently trying to refresh my table every 5 seconds, but I'm not being successful.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Número</th>
      <th>Nome do colaborador / secção</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>               
    <?php
      $req = mysqli_query($con, 'select user_id, user_name from users');                                                                        
      while ($dnn = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "    <td>" . $dnn['user_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "  <td>" . $dnn['user_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
      } 
    ?> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is to refresh the page every 5 seconds and of course if someone edits he will be able to see the changes that were made.

What can I do to complete this action?

Comment: for this you have to use `ajax` and call is inside setInterval

Comment: you can use ajax for that using  setInterval

Comment: Seriously? Negative upvotes just because the stackoverflow editor is so difficult to edit code? Ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like

```
$(function(){
    function getdata(){
       $.ajax({
          url:'getdata.php',
          success:function(response){
              $('#dataTables-example tbody').html(response);
          }
       });
    }
    setInterval(function(){getdata()},5000);
});
```

**getdata.php**

```
<?php
     $req = mysqli_query($con, 'select user_id, user_name from users');
     while ($dnn = mysqli_fetch_array($req)) {
        echo "<tr>
                 <td>" . $dnn['user_id'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $dnn['user_name'] . "</td>
              </tr>";
     }   
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm going to do some testings and I will see my results

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Everything is working, but I'm using a custom table for my website, the problem is when I'm updating, it refreshes and puts all the 200+ rows in one page.

Comment: You need to re initialise your datatable after `$('#dataTables-example tbody').html(response);`.

Comment: Sorry for being newbie, but how can I re initalise the datatable?

Comment: How you initialised datatables in your page on first load? Just copy paste it in success callback function.